# Execution failed for task ':firebase_storage:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-storage

when I install `firebase_storage` in `pubspec.yaml` file like this:

```yaml
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+4
  firebase_core: ^0.4.1
  provider: ^3.1.0
  firebase_storage:
      git:
        url: git://github.com/danysz/flutterfire.git
        ref: master
        path: packages/firebase_storage
```

the error appears as shown below. how to solve it ? please help me

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> * What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':firebase_storage:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
> * Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
> BUILD FAILED in 40s
> Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Actually I want to get multiple images from firebase storage which I already  uploaded in storage for single image I can use `getDownloadURL()` but what to do for multiple images ?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

class Album extends StatefulWidget {

  static const routeName = '/album';

  @override
  _AlbumState createState() => _AlbumState();
}

class _AlbumState extends State<Album> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    body: Expanded(
             child: ListView.builder(
             itemCount: 2,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Column(
                        children: [
                      FutureBuilder(
                        future: _getImage(context, 'user1/abc.jpg'),
                            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                              ConnectionState.done) {
                                print('its done');
                                return CircleAvatar(
                                  radius: 60.0,
                                child: snapshot.data,
                              );
                            }

                          if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                            ConnectionState.waiting) {
                              return CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 60.0,
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                            );
                           }
                            return Container();
                          }
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
           ),
          ],
        ),
      ),

    );
  }

 Future<Widget> _getImage(BuildContext context, String imageName) async {

    Image image;
    await FireStorageService.loadImage(context, imageName).then((value) {
      image = Image.network(
        value.toString(),
        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
      );
    });
    return image;
}
class FireStorageService extends ChangeNotifier {
  FireStorageService();
  static Future<dynamic> loadImage(BuildContext context, String Image) async {
    return await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(Image).getDownloadURL();
  }
}
```

this is the code for single image and it works but for multiple images , I don't know what to do.

Comment: Have you added internet permission?

Comment: Do you need to add `firebase_storage` like that?

Comment: @Andrej I have seen this in stackoverflow to get multiple images so i tried it but it's not working

Comment: You should just type `firebase_storage:` in `pubspec.yaml` dependencies. I've used `firebase_storage` many times and I always added it like this. Never had any issues. Please try it.

Comment: okay i'll try it thanks

Comment: it's not working ,  **error :The method 'listAll' isn't defined for the type 'StorageReference'.**